# HDMI doesn't work when using a USB C docking station

Tags: laptop, multiple-monitors, hdmi, usb-c, docking-station

When connect my USB Type-C adapter to the Thunderbolt/Charging USB Type-C port, the monitor flickers. But the laptop detects the monitor and even can communicate with it so far that it knows its screen size.

##### Things I tried

I bought two more different USB Type-C docking stations and used a second HDMI cable. None of the possible combinations worked. So it's very likely that my monitor is the fault but I don't understand why.

When I don't use a USB Type-C docking station, everything works just fine. For example if I connect my PC via HDMI or my Laptop via the built in HDMI Port.

##### The devices

Laptop: Lenovo ThinkPad E15

Docking Stations:

- https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B09JWCJT7T
- https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B09QFZFWRK (two different kinds one newer and one older, but same ports)

Monitor: Philips C-line 272C4QPJKAB (https://www.philips.at/c-p/272C4QPJKAB_00/brilliance-lcd-monitor-mit-webcam-und-multiview) (HDMI 1.4)

##### HDMI Version

I came up with the idea that there is a version incompatibility, but than I researched and everyone said that HDMI is fully backwards compatible.

##### Not capable throughput

Maybe the HDMI version is so low that it can't handle 2K at all: I lowered the screen resolution as far as I could and did the same for the refresh rate. Nothing happened

##### The flickering

The way the screen flickers is following: Every few seconds a black-white dotted box (similar as the old tv's) which is approximately a two thirds of the screens size appears in the top left corner for a short amount of time.

##### The real question

Has somebody experienced similar things or have an idea what causes this behavior? Or even better does somebody know how to bypass this?

When I try the same setup with my TV everything works fine.

---

#### Update

##### Working

- Connect laptop and monitor directly (without USB C dock)
- Connect laptop and TV (with USB C dock and without)

##### Not working

- Connect laptop and monitor (with USB C dock)

Comment: What revision of HDMI does the cable support?

Comment: Did you have to install drivers to get the video to work? If so, it's a good sign your adapter uses a problematic proprietary technology called "DisplayLink" (note: NOT "DisplayPort". DisplayPort is fine. Display*Link* is garbage.). You should probably look for a simple adapter that uses USB Type C's HDMI alt mode. They're  less expensive, work better, and don't require weird drivers.

Comment: @Spiff I haven't heard about DisplayLink before (know i've googled it). And no that's not an option because I need a docking station. At least: Power Supply, Ethernet and HDMI

Comment: AWM Style @Ramhound I don't know, but it works with my TV (updated question). The only thing I know is that it's a: "AmazonBasics - HIGH SPEED HDMI CABLE WITH ETHERNET - AWM STYLE 20276 VM-1 80°C 30V"

Comment: @Spiff does that mean that my docking station uses display link, but my monitor doesn't support that. My tv on the other hand does?

Comment: @BierDav - You would have to give us the specifics on the docking station in English for anyone here to determine if it's utilizing DisplayLink.

Comment: To be clear -- It works when the monitor HDMI input is connected to the laptop HDMI output.  The "not working" case has the dock plugged into the laptop USB-C, but you didn't tell us whether having the USB-C dock connected causes the laptop HDMI to fail or you are unplugging the monitor from the laptop HDMI and connecting to the dock HDMI.  Please update your question to be very specific how you have connected things.

Comment: I've updated my question. I think now it should be more clear